# Is "number of times " scale, nominal or ordinal? and what is the best test to find any differences if there are?

Tags: nonparametric, variable

In my research, there is a question that was asking the participants about "how many times do you practice physical activity per last week?" (The answer to chose only one: 1- one time. 2- two times. 3- four times. 4- Every day.). **This was in three different times (repeated measurement in three phases).**

**Now,** in SPSS what can I give the type of data? is it scale, nominal or ordinal?

Then which test should I use to find if there are differences between periods (phases)?

I would appreciate any type of help.

Comment: Your survey has collected 'number of days' as an ordinal variable with four categories: `1`. `2`. `3 or 4`, and `every day`. I do wonder what choice people with no physical exercise or exercise on 5 or 6 days of the preceding week were supposed to mark.

Comment: It's interval censored and possibly 0-truncated (you should clarify what's going on with 0). Resist the temptation (which SPSS no doubt expects) to blindly treat it as ordered categories; you can choose to do it, but don't just accept that it's the only choice simply because SPSS doesn't know how to guide you toward a better analysis.